# Feyman diagrams on the basis of counterterms of the $\phi^4$ theory

Tags: renormalization, feynman-diagrams, perturbation-theory

I would like to understand how the Feyman rules for counterterms are derived. For this reason I start with following, certainly a bit naive approach inspired by Peskin & Schroeder.

Once the Lagrangian is decomposed into the renormalized part and the counter terms we have (10.18) in P&S:

$$L = \frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu\phi_r)^2 -\frac{1}{2}m^2\phi_r^2 -\frac{\lambda}{4!}\phi_r^4 +\frac{1}{2}\delta_Z (\partial_\mu\phi_r)^2-\frac{1}{2}\delta_m(\phi_r)^2 -\frac{\delta_\lambda}{4!}\phi_r^4  $$

the Feyman rules for the counterterms can be built. If I consider the counterterms as additional interactions I add the counterterms $C$ with a minus sign (according to $H_I = -L$) to the interaction Hamiltonian (schematically $H_I \rightarrow H_I-C)$ and develop the interacting 2-point function:

$$D:=\langle\Omega|\phi\phi \exp(-i\int H_I d^4x) |\Omega\rangle$$

Actually I would like to study the counterterm related to the field strength renormalization, but as this counterterm is zero in 1. order, I immediately go to second order ($D\approx D^{(0)}+ D^{(1)}+D^{(2)} +\ldots $)

$$D^{(2)} =\int\left[ -\frac{\lambda^2}{2} \langle\Omega|\phi\phi \phi^8  |\Omega\rangle  + \frac{\delta^{(2)}_Z}{4}  \langle\Omega|\phi \partial_\mu\phi_r \partial^\mu\phi_r\phi |\Omega \rangle + \frac{\delta^{(2)}_\lambda}{2\cdot 4!} \langle\Omega|\phi \phi\phi \phi \phi  \phi |\Omega \rangle  + \frac{\lambda}{4!} \langle\Omega|\phi \phi\phi \delta^{(1)}_m\phi \phi\phi\phi\phi|\Omega \rangle   +\ldots  \right]d^4x d^4y$$

The first term seems to correspond to the first diagram in (10.31) + further contractions which also create vacuum bubbles. 
What intrigues  me most is the second term, since it contains derivatives of which it is said that they are not easy to include into an interacting Hamiltonian as the rule $H_I=-L$ is no longer valid. How do we get then the Feyman rule (P&S p. 325)

$$-i\delta_Z p^2 $$

from this ? 
The third term seems to correspond to the second term of (10.31) of P&S probably together with some additional terms with vacuum bubbles.

I also consider the fourth term as interesting, as it consists of a product of the original interacting Hamiltonian $\frac{\lambda}{4!}\phi^4$ and the counterterm $\frac{1}{2}\delta_m(\phi_r)^2$. Are such product terms considered ? Very probably this term will lead to another vacuum bubble, in particular (among other stuff) to a  vacuum bubble which contains a counterterm. Can vacuum bubbles containing counterterms also be discarded and why ?

In the development of the second order 2-point function I did neither respect all appearing minus signs nor probably got the coefficients of the individual terms right, please overlook it. And certainly there are some additional terms I did not mention. Most important is the question with respect to the Feyman rule of the field strength renormalisation.